# How can I install Roboto font locally in my Hugo Wowchemy Site?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, hugo, google-webfonts, wowchemy

I'm setting up a new static website using Hugo and Wowchemy. Wowchemy uses the font Roboto, and I want to provide it locally with my website.

That's what I did:

- I installed the font files (TTF; WOFF) in `static/fonts`
- I changed the value for `fonts` in `params.yaml` to `Roboto` (Yes, that was a desperate move).

Nothing changed when re-starting the server. Using an add on for firefox, I could see that it is still loading the font from the remote site.

So what changes do I have to add in order to let the browser load my local copy of the fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Steps to go:

1. Locate the HUGO template directory (somewhere in `tmp`....)
2. In the template dir, find the `.toml` file defining the template's fonts.
3. Use the URL in the template file to figure out which fonts are loaded with which weights.
4. Download fonts and the associated CSS via https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts
5. Install the fonts into `/static/fonts`.
6. Add the CSS files to `/assets/scss`, changing their suffix to `.scss`
7. Add a `custom.scss` which `@import`s the font definitions. Remember that `@import` is deprecated and will have to be replaced by `@use` directives in the future.

## Long story:

In the beginning, we have to find the template files which are downloaded as modules. The easiest way is to call `hugo server` to make sure the modules have been downloaded, and then go to the path defined in `assets/jsconfig.json`. The path is relative to the file's location and points straight to the corresponding templare directory. In my case, the string value is `"../../../../../tmp/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/modules/wowchemyv5@v5.7.1-0.20221106163805-45466f563a8a/assets/*"` From now on, if we refer to the `template directory`, use the parent directory where this `assets` directory is located in.

Next step: Find the `.toml` file defining the fonts. Go to your hugo build directory and have a look at the configuration file `params.yaml` (located in `config/_default`. Find the key for `appearance/font`, e.g. looking like that:

```yaml
appearance:
  theme_day: minimal
  theme_night: minimal
  font: minimal
  font_size: L
```

Now find the corresponding font file in the theme directory `data/fonts/<....>.toml`. This is the original file which makes sure the fonts are downloaded from google. You will find a parameter defining a call to google, looking like this:

```yaml
# Font style metadata
name = "Minimal"

# Optional Google font URL
google_fonts = "family=Montserrat:wght@400;700 family=Roboto+Monofamily=Roboto:wght@400;700"

# Font families
heading_font = "Montserrat"
body_font = "Roboto"
nav_font = "Roboto"
mono_font = "Roboto Mono"
```

The link tells you which fonts are downloaded and with which weights. Make a note about these values, then create a minimal `data/fonts/<...>.toml` file in your build directory which overwrites the theme's data. For our purpose, it is enough to make sure that no google font is loaded, so we just use this file:

```yaml
# Do not use google fonts via URL
google_fonts = ''

# All further parameters are taken from the theme's 'minimal.toml' file
```

Next, download the fonts with the with the appropriate sizes using the tool https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts. It's pretty straightforward, and we can use the built-in value for the directory where the fonts are located in. Download the fonts and unpack the archive in `static/fonts`.

Then, save the CSS for the downloaded fonts in the directory `assets/<...>.scss`, where `<...>` has to replaced by the font name, like `roboto`. In each SCSS file, also add the following directive to each font declaration:

```scss
font-display: swap;
```

Now create a file `custom.scss` in the same directory which adds your custom font declaration. That can look like this:

```scss
@import "montserrat";
@import "roboto";
@import "roboto-mono";
```

That's it! Restart the server and check that the fonts are downloaded. In Firefox, I use the built-in WebDevTools and check what files are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load a CSS file with a font-face decleration that links to your local file. Personally I would ask this question here: https://discord.com/invite/z8wNYzb.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found the place where the CSS goes into (`admin/scss/custom.scss`), only remaining riddle is the precise declaration of the font. I'd love to ask at the Discord place, but the server wants my phone number and birthday for sign up; I'm hesistant to use it.